# Uninstalling Intel Proset/Wireless Bluetooth while upgrading to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, uninstall

I purchased Windows Upgrade 8 and ran Windows Update Assistant on existing windows 7.

However, It is asking me to uninstall Intel Wireless bluetooth, as it is not compatible with windows 8. I did just that and in spite of uninstalling it successfully, it is giving a message "Manually Uninstall". I dont know what this means? is it successfully uninstalled or not, and if not how do I uninstall it completely.

I posted this on Microsoft forum also and found many users are facing this issue. Noone from Microsoft has answered there.

```
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/problem-in-uninstalling-intel-prosetwireless/5e1c4a29-726e-4968-a787-80b45778d14c?page=1
```

I have tried CCleaner, Microsoft fixit and other tools but still no help.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I fixed it:

• Go to `services.msc` via RUN.

• Stop these 3 services

[image]

• Delete the bluetooth folder located under

[image]

• Delete the services that are associated with them in cmd (run as administrator) with:

```
sc delete "Bluetooth Device Monitor"
sc delete "Bluetooth Media Service" 
sc delete "Bluetooth OBEX Service"
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver from here and run the setup:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22548&lang=eng

If you use the 32Bit Windows run the *32.exe* file, if you use a 64Bit Windows run the *64.exe* file.

Comment: I am using windows 7. I want ot upgrade to windows 8. These drivers are for windows 8.

Comment: and I posted the link to the drivers so that you can download them. Remove them in Win7, updrade to Win8 and install the new drivers.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. The problem is even after removing drivers from Win7, the upgraded Assistant still tells me to remove them.

Comment: have you only deleted the device in device manager or uninstalled the complete software?

Comment: I have uninstalled the complete software.